# Вывести весь объект из Map

Tags: javascript

```js
let map = new Map ([
['Домик', 4],
['Стул', 3],
['Шкаф', 2],
])

let obj = Object.fromEntries(map); 
alert(obj.Домик); //Выводит лишь одно значение за раз, как сделать так, чтобы за раз выводило все значения?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let map = new Map([
  ['Домик', 4],
  ['Стул', 3],
  ['Шкаф', 2],
]);

let obj = Object.fromEntries(map); 

Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  console.log(key, value)
})
```